# Filter and return results Springboot, Spring Jpa, Hibernate Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I created two table and they are linked together by foreign key.

Table: users

```
Id   name          address_id
1    John           1
2    William        2
3    Scott          1
4    Mary           1
```

Table: Address

```
Id     city
1       USA
2       Frank
```

This is Entity

User.java

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.FetchType;
 import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
 import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
 import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
  import javax.persistence.Table;


 @Table(name = "users")
 @Entity
 public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
private Address address;

public User () {}

public User  (String name) { 
    this.name=name;
}  

public long getId() {
    return id; 
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

    public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
   }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
    }
   }
```

Address.java

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Table(name = "address")
@Entity
public class Address {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
private String city;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "address", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<User> users= new HashSet<>();

public Address () {}

public Address (String city) { 
    this.city=city;
}

public long getId() {
    return id; 
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
}
```

I have successfully created, modified, and deleted functions. I am trying to create a function to list the list by same value but still with no success. For example, if I want to list all "names" with address "1", it will output the values "John", "William", "Mary". I tried to use @Query but it also failed. Any suggestions or sample code for me? Thanks very much

Comment: What `@Query` that failed did you try?

Comment: ..and how you implement your DAO? with repositories? maybe you can include it too, then. There are many ways you can solve this.. query generation, filtering the stream afterwards, etc.

Comment: Check specification api. Specification will be the easiest and best way to do this

Comment: can you give me sample code or more specifically? Thanks @Nikolas Charalambidis

Comment: can you give me sample code or more specifically? Thanks @Giorgi Tsiklauri

Comment: can you give me sample code or more specifically? Thanks @Sridhar Patnaik